Bike post slips down
I have a metal bike post and frame and annoyingly after a ride I find my bike post slides down. its the stock seat so i'm sure it is the correct size.
Its a quick release so it is quite hard to tighten anymore than i do. I heard of people on reddit suggesting this sorta stuff but it seems to suggest it is designed to work with carbon frames.
Anyone got any suggestions to avoid seat slippage?

How old is the bike?    What brand of bike is it?   Metal fatigue is a thing and the QR can be elongated with age (yes, even the short ones for a saddle)    A clear photo of your seatpost/frame area might be useful here too

Try putting some old rubber tubing or other rubber between the post and the frame to increase friction.

A picture helps. Usually quick release mechanisms have an adjustable nut at the other end of the skewer. Have you tightened this a half turn? Note also: checking seat stability before your ride is a critical safety check. Hold the frame between your legs and give the seat a few hard yanks to the left and right, if it moves it's not safe to ride. This will keep you safe as you investigate any of the many options below.

Carefully check the seat tube for cracks or deformations. If you or a previous owner rode with the seatpost too high, you can crack or deform the seat tube, and in each case you get the sensation of clamping the seatpost down toight but it will never achieve a toight fit.

Carbon paste also helps gripping on metal seat posts and frames.
But first i would try putting some grease on the interface between handle and collar of the quick release clamp. This allows you to make it tighter while still being able to move it by hand.

Thanks i tried the paste and it worked a treat!

Not every seatpost or seat tube comes out of the factory at exactly 27.2000mm with zero variance. One or both of your seatpost and seat tube could be out of tolerance in some fashion - that is, they're not within the tolerances established by industry for a nominal dimension of 27.2mm, e.g. maybe the seatpost is really 27.18mm or something. You can take a pair of calipers and measure them, but basically the seatpost should slide into the tube with some friction.
The other issue is that quick release clamps don't clamp as strongly as standard ones, and you may have got a low quality clamp.
If the seatpost fits really loosely in the tube, you could take an aluminum can, cut a shim, and put it around the seatpost. This is the old style fix. Otherwise, yes, carbon paste is not only for carbon fiber. It's called that because carbon components, especially light ones, tend to have relatively low torque specifications. Last, if those don't work, get a better seat clamp. If you must have a QR clamp, then most likely a Salsa Flip Off would work.

On one of my unicycles - the cheap one - the QR never gave enough clamping force, but a nut and bolt in the same (welded on) clamp fixed it.  On bikes a second clamp just round the post above the seat tube can be a good backup (possibly used upside down)

You can also replace the quick release clamp with something that holds better.  As already noted, quick release clamps tend not to work very well.
Such as a double clamp double clamp that both clamps on the seat post itself as well as compressing the frame to clamp on the seat post.


Depending on the age of the bike either post or seat-tube may have worn down enough at the clamp point through repeated height-adjustments to mean that a QR will no longer create enough friction to hold it in place.
MTB are vulnerable to this issue as seat height is frequently adjusted in combination with mud and water.
My fix for this situation was to use a bolted seat collar which may fit around the tube profile better and can be torqued slightly higher. Make sure you get the size that matches your seat tube.
Budget versions are generally fairly low cost ($10 - $20) so could be tried with minimum financial penalty if it doesn't work.


The assembly paste will absolutely work for you. The Parktool version says it is for "Carbon and alloy". I would highly recommend going to your local bike shop and asking for a drop or two as a whole tube will last the average cyclist several lifetimes.
The bolt seat collar is an option as well if you are not adjusting the seat height frequently.
I had a similar problem with a mountain bike I own and it slipped even with a bolted seat collar torqued to spec. The friction paste solved the issue for me.
